# Access var this from lazy load load()

Tags: javascript, this, lazy-loading

I have this function :

```
if (msgContainer.length) {
    $(msgContainer).find('img[data-src]').each(function() {
        var self = this,
            lsrc = $(self).data('src'),
            img = new Image();

        img.src = lsrc;
        $(img).load(function() {
            self.src = this.src;

            $(self).data('src', null);
        });
    });
}
```

And I try to use this.scrollToBottom() inside the load function.

I tried to put this in a variable "tes"t and bind this variable inside the each function but this.scrollToBottom() return undefined.
How to do this please ?

Comment: What type is msgContainer? I see you checking its length, but then putting it as a JQuery argument. *that* might be the thing you want to scroll to the bottom of, not the `img[data-src]`.

Comment: @Katana314 msgContainer is a div. I want to scroll the parent container of msgContainer which is this